# Как взаимодействовать с нескольками input type=file

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Подскажите как на одной странице сразу взаимодействовать с двумя и больше инпут file.
Хочу сделать, что бы при добавлении картинок к тексту приписывался количество загружаемых картинок.
Например: Прикрепить (3)
Но у меня работает только с одним инпутом.

```js
const inputFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.js-inputfile');
inputFiles.forEach((file, i) => {
        file.addEventListener('change', ( {target} ) => {
            const fileWrap = target.closest('.js-inputfile');
            const fileText = fileWrap.querySelector('.file__form-file-label > span');
            console.log(file);
            fileText.textContent = `Прикрепить файл (${target.files.length})`;
        })
    });
```

Comment: не очень понял вопрос, мб вам нужен аттрибут `multiple` в `input`?

Comment: Атрибут уже есть. У меня на странице 3 инпут file. И мне надо взаимодействовать с этими тремя инпутами. Что бы выводить сколько я картинок выбрал (то есть длина). А получается только с одним.

Comment: выведите html-разметку, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо большое что откликнулись. Исправил свою ошибку. У всех инпутов был одинаковый id (который связывал стилизованный инпут). Поставил разный и всё за работало)))